# how to convert files into executable files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ros-fuerte distro in ubuntu12.04
I have written two cpp file named talker.cpp and listener.cpp in src and i add two lines seeing below in CMakeLists.txt file

rosbuild_add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)

now when i give a command $make it displays

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
actually the two files are not found in bin directory
would you pleas help me how to convert cpp files to executable files and how to execute that nodes in ROS environment please explain me in steps

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51659/how-to-convert-files-into-executable-files/) by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-08

Post score: -3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-08**:
Please do not spam ROS answers by repeating your questions. You might find this helpful: http://ros.org/wiki/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lool at the answers to the same question you asked yesterday:
http://answers.ros.org/question/51609/about-executable-files/

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1